# Hadoop Cassandra integration design

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra, apache-pig

I have `3 Cassandra nodes` lets say `c1,c2 and c3`. And i want to integrate Hadoop with Cassandra so that i can run my pig scripts on Hadoop to read data from Cassandra and analyze it. SO i have hadoop set up like this `h1 as name-node , h2 as data-node, c1 as data-node and c3 as data-node. Here h2 node is a only hadoop data-node and not with the any Cassandra node`. My question here is **`while reading and processing data through pig/mapredude does it uses h2 data-node?`**

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't you need to install hadoop datanodes on all the cassandra nodes?
My understandings are that map-reduce uses HDFS datanodes to store intermediate results before reducing data. So I think it is quite possible for H2 to be used. It is my guess and I'm looking forward for corrections